# com mysql jdbc exceptions jdbc4 mysql syntax error exception

Tags: java

```
    private void jButton4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

        // TODO add your handling code here:

        try{

            String CompanyID=ComID.getText();

            String User_name=Username.getText();

            String password=Password.getText();

            String post_held=jTextField2.getText();

            String azu="update staffs set StaffID= 

'"+CompanyID+"',UserName='"+User_name+"',Password='"+password+"','Post_held="+post_held+"'where StaffID='"+CompanyID+"' ";

            //azucar="update staffs set StaffID= ?,?,?,?";

            az.psst = az.conn.prepareStatement(azu);

            az.psst.execute(azu);

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, 
            "Updated!","Frsc",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

        }catch (Exception e){

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);

        }deb();


    }
```

- List item

---

Comment: What are you trying to ask?

Comment: @sambayour Can you give a bit of context for what's going on and what you are asking? You can also make the code look more attractive by indenting each line with 4 spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`'Post_held="+post_held+"'where` should be
`Post_held='"+post_held+"' where`.

---

On a different note: **DO NOT** build a SQL statement using string concatenation like that, or you leave yourself open to [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks, which will allow attackers to delete/steal all you data.

Use a `PreparedStatement` with parameter markers (`?`) and set the values on the statement object.